# Calculate value of animation in useAnimaionStyle

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

I am working with react native reanimated 2

To make animations with opacity

This example works as well

```
  const width = useSharedValue(50);
  const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      opacity: width.value,
    };
  });
  return <Animated.View style={[styles.box, animatedStyle]} />;
```

But when I want to calculate any value that does not work

I get an error

```
const width = useSharedValue(50);
  const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      opacity: cond(greaterThan(width.value, 10), 1, 0),
    };
  });
  return <Animated.View style={[styles.box, animatedStyle]} />;
```

I get errors like that

> cannot read property 'onFrame' on null

How can I calculate the value in 'useAmimationStyle'?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using reanimated v1 functions on the v2. You could do:

```js
 const width = useSharedValue(50);
 const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {   
    return {
      opacity: width.value > 10 ? 1 :0
    };
  });
 return <Animated.View style={[styles.box, animatedStyle]} />;
```

But the issue with this is that opacity wont really be animated;  it would just instantaneously go to 1 or 0 when width.value got around 10. To get animation like opacity changes use [interpolate](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/api/miscellaneous/interpolate/#example):

```js
const width = useSharedValue(50);
  const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      width:width.value,
      opacity: interpolate(
        width.value,
        //input range
        [0, 10, 50],
        // output ramge
        [0, 0, 1]
      ),
    };
  });
 return <Animated.View style={[styles.box, animatedStyle]} />;
```

[Demo](https://snack.expo.dev/z_Sf0mtkL)